# Understanding Haskell

Tags: list, haskell

Can someone help me understand how this function in Haskell works?

```
f :: Eq t => t -> [t] -> [t]
f x [] = []
f x (y: ys) | (x==y) = [x]
f x (y: ys) | otherwise = y : f x ys
```

My understanding so far is that the function `f` tests the equality of variable `t` and list of type `t` and returns a list of type `t`.

If passed `x` and an empty set `f` will return an empty set.

If passed `x` and a list where `y` heads the list `or` `x` is equal to `y` then it will return a list containing `x`.

If passed `x` and a list where `y` heads the list `or` anything else then it will return a list headed by `y` and the contents of the list returned from a recursive call to `f` using `x` and list `ys`?

Is that correct?

Secondly I don't know what the equality being tested is? Is it testing to see if `x` is contained within a listor checking to see if `x` is heading the list?

Can someone explain please?

Answer (score 1):

Probably better to pay attention to the terminal cases.  Empty list being one and head of list equals to the given element the other.  Otherwise, it's going to recursively operate until one of the two cases happens.

By hand go over what will be the returned list for these two

```
f 3 [1,2]
```

and

```
f 3 [1,2,3,4,5]
```

It's better to discover yourself but I guess you're not there yet.

For

```
f 3 [1,2] = 1: (f 3 [2]) = 1: 2: (f 3 []) = [1,2]
```

other one similarly

```
f 3 [1..5] = 1: (f 3 [2..5]) = 1: 2: (f 3 [3,4,5]) = 1: 2: [3] = [1,2,3]
```

Comment: OK, so f 3 [1,2] will go to the recursive case and give f 3 [2], which will go to the recursive case which will be f 3 [] which will return an empty set? and the f 3 [1,2,3,4,5] will do the same until it gets to f 3 [3,4,5] which will return [3]? Is that right?

Comment: almost but not there yet, you forgot that `y :` is appending elements to the result.

Comment: I'm not sure how it would terminate if no elements are removed?

Comment: Each recursive case is smaller than the last: `ys` has strictly fewer elements than `(y:ys)`.

Comment: remember two terminal states.  either nothing left or value matches a list element.

Comment: So where the the y appended?